# Recette de poulet or recette du poulet

Tags: prépositions, genre

Why do we say “recette de poulet”, not “recette du poulet”, when “poulet” is masculine? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an explanation but one can say "Une recette de poulet" or "La recette du poulet".

Comment: The fact *poulet* is masculine is irrelevant here. You might have equally asked "why *recette de tarte* and not *recette de la tarte*?".

Answer (score 3):

- « Recette *de* poulet » signifie un recette à base de poulet (poulet rôti, poulet tandoori, poulet au cidre)
- « Recette *du* poulet » signifie une recette proposée **par** le poulet.

Par contre on peut dire :

- « Recette du poulet au cidre » qui signifie une recette avec du poulet et du cidre (entre autres)

Comment: Il faut ajouter que le "du" est une contraction de "de le", il faut distinguer l'article défini de l'article indéfini. La différence est alors facilement identifiable, "Recette de poulet" signifie une recette concernant la viande de poulet en général, la "Recette du poulet" concerne la recette d'un poulet en particulier (qu'il soit sujet ou objet d'ailleurs)